how can I vectorize this double summation in Matlab?
I have to find $P(s,t) =\sum^2_{j_1=1}\sum^4_{j_2=1}  x_j s^{j_1-1} t^{j_2-1}$
with $j = (j_1-1)2+j_2$  and x a vector of size (1×4) ( in this example a random x is fine). The less efficient manner to deal with this double summation is to use 2 "for loops", but i want to make  it more efficient, for implementation : (the code : https://ibb.co/D5Lw42k)
Looking at the behaviour of j we can see that j is simply a $1:m^2$, so this could help with the summation, also i noticed that sum(sum()) could be used to avoid the "for loops" passing s and t as vectors, but this can cause a bit of problems due to the different array sizes (I would just be able to calculate size 2 vectors at a time), also$ j_1-1 $ and  $j_2-1$ could just be $0:m-1, 0:m-1$. Even noticing all this facts I am not able to calculate such a function $P $ (I didn't make it an actual function in the code shown because that's  not what i am having problems with, once I have made the full working vectorization I know how to make it a function)
EDIT : I'm fine with giving any more info and sending more of what I have done if asked, I'm also fine with any kind of feedback if you actually have some opinion to share regarding the post so why have to downvote without even saying anything ? What's the point?

The questions on this site are nearly all about math. Your question is about vectorizing an algorithm, which is about coding, not math. You may have more luck at a software-dedicated site, like the Matlab forums.

@RobinSparrow This question is not truly about vectorializing an "algorithm" ; nevertheless you are right in saying that the probability to have answers is larger on sites like here.

@JeanMarie, vectorizing a loop or computation then. But, also, why would you not consider this looped, deterministic matrix generation procedure an algorithm? Not arguing, I'm curious.

@RobinSparrow Yes, I think now that you are right...

The expression you are using is called a bilinear form : see coordinates expression here.
A first answer, exploiting the easy treatment of matrices in Matlab, is as follows.
Let $i_k=j_k-1$ and $x_j=x_{i_1,i_2}$
We consider the case where indices $i_1$ and $i_2$ are in $[0,1]$ and $R$ is a random $2 \times 2$ matrix, i.e., the initial expression is :
$$\sum_{x_1=0}^{1}\sum_{x_2=0}^{1}x_{i_1,i_2}s^{i_1}t^{i_2}$$
$$=\pmatrix{s^0&s^1}\pmatrix{x_{00}&x_{01}\\x_{10}&x_{11}}\pmatrix{t^0\\t^1}\tag{1}$$
Remark : expression (1) is legit : we can multiply matrices which are
$$(1 \times n) * (n \times n) * (n \times 1)$$
 n=10;
 s=rand;t=rand;X=rand(n,n);
 K=0:(n-1);
 U=s.^K;V=t.^K; % line vectors
 P=U*X*V'

Edit : The next step is to define matrix $X$ by $X_{i_1,i_2}=2 i_1+(i_2+1)$ as well by a (hopefuly) more efficient way than to do it by a double loop.
Here is how by using "exterior" products with vectors of "ones" :
     n=4;
     K=0:(n-1);
     U=ones(1,n);
     X=2*K'*U+U'*(K+1)


in this way the U and V part will be used for calculating the s and t "parts" but i don't understand what happends to the x, my fault because i initially wrote in the question x as a matrix while it just is a vector

the $x$ are plainly gathered in matrix $R$. I will be going to add it in my answer.

i tried the code with s = 1 t =2 and x = 1 : 4 , x = reshape (x,2,2) and i get two different results from the summations, one is 16(for loops) and the other is 17 using the vectorization, why?

Reshape works columnwise, i.e., gives here $\pmatrix{1&3\  2 & 4}$. Haven't you taken the transpose of this matrix ?

didnt't take the transpose

I have checked : indeed, one obtains $17$ when the matrix is as given just above, and $16$ when you take the transpose of this matrix.

one more question, i need to calculate this P for a certain number of values (ex 100) and then  calculate $d=|P(s,t)-f(s,t)|/|f(s,t)|$ with $f(s,t) = f (s, t) = t + 1
9 st$ i did like this but i'm not certain it works correctly : i made a for loop for calculating it's P(i) and the d(i) like this :
for i =1 :N
X=reshape(x,m(k),m(k))';
K=0:(m(k)-1);
U=s(i).^K;
V=t(i).^K;
P(i)=UXV';
fst=f(s(i) ,t(i) );
P(i) = abs( (P(i)-fst ) / (fst) ) ;
end

There are different things that are difficult to grasp for me : for example the loop index is $i$, but, just after there is a $m(k)$ which means that there is another loop with index k (?) Besides, by $P(i)=UXV'$ you surely mean $P(i)=UXV'$ ?
